# hide / show div with a button not in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using elementor for my wordpress site and I wish to have a button in a first div (section) that control if a second and separate div (section) is display or not. I've tried to use the checkbox hack but it's working only if the checkbox is in the div as the content https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Is there a solution to use CSS or even javascript ? If you advice to me to use javascript I'll put in my function.php file and as I'm begginer in javascript can you please write all the function I have to implement into my function.php file.

Basically it means :

```
<div>button</div> <div>content to show and hide on click on the button</div>
```

Best regards,
Clément

Comment: You need to try something yourself and if you are stuck, come back here to get some support.

Comment: Hi! You should avoid asking specifically for all code.
You might receive it anyway but it just seems like you are not here to learn, but rather to get your job done by someone else. And secondly just search the google first (literally first result searching `onclick hide`  is https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp ) :)

Comment: Hi, sorry if it looks like I need a service provision rather than support. Believe me I digged before asking here. And your link didn't appears in my search but seems to do the job ! And about asking for the whole code I asked it in order to understand how it works cause I didn't have any clue how to start it. Anyway I'll keep your advice in mind for the futur. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of yours answers! Here what I use:

```
<button onclick="myFunctionopenclose()">Click Me</button>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">content to hide and show</div>
<script> function myFunctionopenclose() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none"; } 
else {
x.style.display = "block";}}
```

Best regards,
Clément

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery:

1-Put an id to your DIV

```
<div id = "btn_show"> button </div> <div id = "show"> content to show and hide on click on the button </div>
```

2-Call jquery to display it

```
$("#btn_show").click(function(){
 $("#show").show();
  //or
 $("#show").hide();
});
```

And jquery you can call it with CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript without any library this could be very easy but you need to put an id on your divand your button.

```
<div id="myButton">button</div> 
<div id="myDiv">
  content to show and hide on click on the button
</div>
```

Then you just add a script section like this : (it just need to be after your div and your button in the DOM)

```
<script>
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  myDiv.classList.toggle('visible'):
});
</script>
```

And at last, you need a css like this:

```
.visible {
  display: none;

}
```

Comment: Why not use onclick for the button at least? While the css togle class might be a nice ideea you should at the very least use onclick instead of id and addEventListener.

Comment: Yeah probably but i never use the onclick. So i don't realy know how it is realy working. To be sure the code i give him works, i didn't use it^^. But i am gonna look it thanks.